# Change "span" class when using Responsive utility classes - Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap, but I'm having slight difficulties on a particular element.

Here is a 'Scaffolding' markup already provided by the interface, which I will use as an example.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span6">
    Level 1 column
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span3">Level 2</div>
      <div class="span3">Level 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, to help this case... There are 'Responsive utility classes', which you can check out here - http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive

So, what I am looking to do is simply change the `class="span3"` to, for example, `class="span6"` when I am using the 'responsive utility class' `.visible-tablet.`

Initially, I thought that it would miraclely automatically change to the 'max-width', but it didn't, unfortunately.

Comment: Thats not how responsive designs work :/ With responsive design you can change the CSS, not the HTML, so you just need to change the styles of `span3`. What you want can be done with javascript, not with CSS.

Answer (score 1):

As @scumah pointed out, you're not going to change the class using CSS.  For that you would use JS.

However, if you want to change the characteristics of a class (in this case `span3`) when it is contained in an element with a given class (here `visible-tablet`) that's just a matter of getting your CSS selectors working:

```
.visible-tablet .span3 {
  width: 352px;
}​
```

This would change the `span3` to be identical to what is, by default, the width of a `span6`.

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zf8az/)

However, all this seems a bit hackish, so you might want to reconsider what essentially you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks both for your replies! You've been a great help.